# OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed **opencv version 1.0.1** and when i use **cv2.imwrite()** method it throws me following error

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the
specified extension) in imwrite_, file
/io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp, line 604 Traceback
(most recent call last):   File "scan.py", line 78, in <module>
findContours(image,screenCnt,orig,ratio,outputPath)   File /home/Verchaska/dev/aneesh/contours.py", line 26, in findContours
cv2.imwrite(filename,warped) cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:604: error: (-2) could
not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_
```

Comment: Use `print filename` before `cv2.imwrite()` to see if you passed a valid [extension](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite)

Comment: Yes, I checked it and I am passing the ".jpg" extension

Comment: Try once with `.png` extension or other possible extensions.

Comment: Version 1.0.1? Really? Why are you using this obsolete version?

Comment: I am working with a Tesseract software, it is support is not extended to all the OS's. And its dependent libraries and version compatibility has become problem for the project to run. We could get through this version that is why we are using it.

Comment: please share the sample code that you're working with

Comment: OpenCV 1.0.1 is nonsense -- such version was [never officially released](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog_v10-v21). (And if it was, it would be about 10 years obsolete by now). The only thing that matches such version name is [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv/1.0.1) on pypi,  and you don't need to look to hard to figure out it's just some junk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use extension with file like:

```
filename = 'inference/output/images/imagename.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(filename, file)
```